# ConcurrentDictionary with "expensive" value

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have a multi-threaded application that implements `async` methods. The application communicates over RabbitMq and at times needs to do a costly operation (`BasicConsume` on an `IModel`). I have a ConcurrentDictionary where I keep `IModel` (key) and it's `IBasicConsumer` (value) in order to avoid additional round-trips to the message broker.

On start-up, multiple executions reach the same section of the code where it looks if the consumer (value) exists. In the first ~40 cases the answer is no, but I don't want to do 40 `BasicConsume`, only one or perhaps two depending on the `IModel` (key) provided.

Using a `lock` statement introduces a performance hit that is not acceptable.

Currently, I'm solving the problem as follows

```
var consumerTcs = new TaskCompletionSouce<IBasicConsumer>();
if (_consumerDictionary.TryAdd(channel, consumerTcs))
{
    var newConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    newConsumer.Model.BasicConsume(queue, false, newConsumer)
    consumerTcs.TrySetResult(newConsumer);
    return consumerTcs.Task;
}
else
{
    return _consumerDictionary[channel].Task;
}
```

That is

1. Use a `TaskCompletionSource` (non-expencive) as the value of the dictionary
2. Use `TryAdd`, and if successful do the expensive operation
3. If unsuccessful, assume that the key exists and return the `TaskCompletionSource.Task`

However, I still create `TaskCompletionSources` that I don't use, which feels a bit ugly to me. Any suggestions to how I might solve this problem without the performance hit of a `lock` and without wasting clock cycles on creating objects that is not used?

Comment: How did you measure this unacceptable performance hit?

Comment: Also, this is what  `GetOrAdd(TKey, Func<TKey, TValue>)` is for, use it instead of the `TryAdd` and the possible race condition, i.e. if  you ever remove values from the dictionary, `TryAdd` may return `false` but then obtaining the value may throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: @acelent measured performance by running the code with nested tasks (20x outer and 50'000x inner) with a stopwatch. However `GetOrAdd` might be what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: `GetOrAdd` does not work, as the `valueFactory` will be called until a `valueFactory` returns its value. This results in multiple unwanted roundtrips to the message broker.

Comment: You'd use `GetOrAdd` (with `Func<>`) to avoid creating many `TaskCompletionSouce<IBasicConsumer>`.  It's nothing more than a `TryGet`, optionally followed by a `TryAdd` when there's no value, in essence reversing the logic you present.  It may create a few unnecessary ones initially if there's a lot of contention, but the only way to create only one at all is with a lock around the block.  Alas, with `GetOrAdd`, you have no direct notion if the returned object is the one you created or not, unless you set a captured variable, so a manual `TryGet`->`TryAdd` is simpler and does the same work.